# Loading an .exe with .txt information

Tags: mpd

I have the Music Player Daemon version for Windows, running together with ncmpcpp through Cygwin.
Since just opening the MPD executable it won't recognize my libraries, etc, I have setup some lines of information in a .txt file, and I drag it onto the executable for it to work fine.
Is there anyway to implement those lines in the executable, without dragging the .txt file every time I want to open it?

The current lines are:

```
port                    "6600"
music_directory         "C:/Music"
playlist_directory      "C:/MPD/.mpd/playlists"
db_file                 "C:/MPD/.mpd/mpd.db"
log_file                "C:/MPD/.mpd/mpd.log"

audio_output {
    type                    "winmm"
    name                    "My Windows Device"
}
```

Where "music_directory" is the destination of my musics, and all the other lines contains information for the MPD files and the audio output.

Comment: I guess you just need to tell mpd to use configuration file. Dragging the file causes the filename to be passed as an argument to the exe file. You can create a shortcut to the exe and in the shortcut properties you insert the txt config file name after the exe.

Comment: As Marki555 stated you can pass the config via a conf file (your txt-file) to the mpd.exe by adding it as an argument. Also, see the mpd man page!